# attaching outlook to a web application

Tags: asp.net

If I need a web application to be able to work interactively with Outlook, how can this be programmed/ inculcated into the web application so that data can go straight into the database from outlook? (Basically, if I want to program my own CRM, how can I get it to interact with MS Outlook's email platform? I want the user to be able to choose a contact, see his details in the web form, and have a corner of the window have all the outlook communications with this person, including the option to send/see emails, meaning having a mini version of Outlook displayed on the screen, relating to the contact. And thereafter to be able to change the CRM based on email responses.)

Comment: I'd start by researching how to interact with Outlook programmatically. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/) is probably a good place to start. Otherwise, this question is far too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to look into the [Microsoft Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) which allow you to communicate with a Microsoft Exchange server / service (or with Office 365).

Using EWS you can do many things with an exchange account, see this quote from the link above:

> The EWS Managed API is the recommended interface for developing client applications that use EWS and Autodiscover to communicate with Exchange. You can use the EWS Managed API to work with email messages, calendar, task, and contact information, and allow programmatic access to mailboxes, public folders, and public folder mailboxes. The API enables programmatic access to most Exchange resources in a more intuitive format than the underlying EWS SOAP messages or the now deprecated generated proxy classes. Nearly all of the functionality available in the underlying EWS operations is available in the EWS Managed API, although there are minor differences.
>
> The EWS Managed API is essentially a wrapper for EWS. EWS SOAP calls are sent by the EWS Managed API and the EWS SOAP responses are also parsed and handled by the EWS Managed API.

Comment: Alternatively (not all outlook clients have / can be connected to exchange) you can distribute client application or outlook plugin that will help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` and then adding the following using statement

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Should give you a start to work with Outlook programmatically. From there the documentation for the Interop library(Which can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.aspx) should be of use to you.

Comment: Using Interop in a Web Application is not a good idea, as you're essential spawning a outlook / office application on the IIS server and then "remote" control it, which is very prone to errors - especially when there are multiple users active at the same time.